# Let $S$ be the subset of $M(\mathbb{R})$ consisting of matrices of the form:

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification

The proof I read on slader seemed like it only used either $1$ or $2$ matrices to prove this when the question asks for all matrices of a certain form (when $x+y = 1$).

Let $S$ be the subset of $M(\mathbb{R})$ consisting of matrices of the form: $\begin{pmatrix}a & a\\\ b & b\end{pmatrix}$.

If $x + y = 1$, show that $\begin{pmatrix}x & x\\\ y & y\end{pmatrix}$ is not a left identity in $S$.

If $\begin{pmatrix}x & x\\\ y & y\end{pmatrix}$ is a left identity, then we have 
$\begin{pmatrix}x & x\\\ y & y\end{pmatrix}$$\begin{pmatrix}0 & 0\\\ 1 & 1\end{pmatrix}$ = $\begin{pmatrix}x & x\\\ y & y\end{pmatrix}$ = $\begin{pmatrix}0 & 0\\\ 1 & 1\end{pmatrix}$.

But $\begin{pmatrix}x & x\\\ y & y\end{pmatrix}$$\begin{pmatrix}1 & 1\\\ 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}$ = $\begin{pmatrix}x & x\\\ y & y\end{pmatrix}$ = $\begin{pmatrix}1 & 1\\\ 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}$

which implies the contradiction that  $\begin{pmatrix}x & x\\\ y & y\end{pmatrix}$ = $\begin{pmatrix}0 & 0\\\ 1 & 1\end{pmatrix}$ = $\begin{pmatrix}1 & 1\\\ 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}$.

Hence $\begin{pmatrix}x & x\\\ y & y\end{pmatrix}$ is not a left identity in $S$.

Is this a correct proof without using the fact that $x+y = 1$?

Comment: Your example has that $x+y =1$. You already used it.

Comment: Take matrices with $2$'s instead of $1$'s. Isn't it the same argument?

Comment: Check by multiplying. You will get $x+y =1 $ again.

Comment: If you use $2$'s on top and $0$'s on bottom and then $0$'s on top and $2$'s on bottom for the same argument  saying these two different matrices are equal you have $x+y=2$.

Comment: I will show you wait.

Comment: I realize the relevant part is the variable matrix, not the elements I am right multiplying by. So this makes a bit more sense although I am not sure why this condition was included in the hypothesis.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96142/discussion-between-rick-and-derek-luna).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $S = \left\{ A \in \mathcal{M}_{2 \times 2}(\mathbb{R}) :\ A= \begin{bmatrix}a &a\\\ b& b \end{bmatrix}\right\}$.

Then, $\begin{bmatrix}x &x\\\ y& y \end{bmatrix}$ is a left identity if $\begin{bmatrix}x &x\\\ y& y \end{bmatrix} \cdot\begin{bmatrix}a &a\\\ b& b \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}ax+bx & ax+bx\\\ ay+by& ay+by \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}a &a\\\ b& b \end{bmatrix}$ for all $\begin{bmatrix}a &a\\\ b& b \end{bmatrix} \in S, \begin{bmatrix}a &a\\\ b& b \end{bmatrix}\ne 0_{S}.$

$\Rightarrow ax+bx = a$ and $ay+by = b \Rightarrow x= \frac{a}{a+b}, y = \frac{b}{a+b} \Rightarrow x+y = 1$.

So one may conclude that $\begin{bmatrix}x &x\\\ y& y \end{bmatrix}$ is an identity of $S$ if $x+y =1$. But then even if $x+y =1$, by taking

$\begin{bmatrix}a &a\\\ b& b \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}0 &0\\\ 1& 1 \end{bmatrix}$ once and $\begin{bmatrix}1 &1\\\ 0& 0 \end{bmatrix}$ second, we obtain $\begin{bmatrix}x &x\\\ y& y \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}0 &0\\\ 1& 1 \end{bmatrix}$ and

$\begin{bmatrix}x &x\\\ y& y \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}1 &1\\\ 0& 0 \end{bmatrix}$ respectively, which is not possible.

Comment: Thank you for showing me this. It is confusing to me because it seems "implicit" as in once you make the assumptions regarding the matrix being the identity. Because like I said if I use some matrix where $x + y$ clearly is not $1$ (like the matrix with $2$'s on top) then somewhere in the problem it forces the sum to be $1$ as well?...

Comment: Yes, that is the point. The condition is given because the question wants you to check that even if the condition holds (as one would obtain by calculation as above) a left identity is not possible. This is visible from your proof.

Comment: @DerekLuna please accept any of the answers if they satisfy you so that the question is settled. :)

Answer (score 1):

Your proof is correct and you *haven't* used the condition that $x+y=1$. In fact, the set of matrices in question has not any left identity. So, whether $x+y=1$ is irrelevant.

I believe that the "left" in the question is a typo. The question makes more sense if it is talking about *right* identities.

Comment: The previous part to this question was a question with a right identity, so I am not sure. Thanks.